# Calling Trimble Connect APIs from a C# App

Tags: c#

I am trying to use a C# application to interact with a Trimble Connect Project. To do this, I'm trying to follow this link: [APIs tutorial](https://developer.tekla.com/trimble-connect/documentation/code-example-get-name-active-trimble-connect-project).

The problem is that after adding a lot of missed dependencies I'm stuck with this:

> Could not load type 'System.ServiceModel.Description.DispatcherSynchronizationBehavior' from assembly 'System.ServiceModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is becasue you are trying to build this application using .Net Core framework. .net Core core 5.0 framework did changes on ServiceModel along with other. You can refer this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/dotnet-five)

**Here how you can use application**. As per documentation of [SDK](https://developer.tekla.com/trimble-connect/documentation/trimble-connect-net-sdk), they supported .Net Framework 4.0 and onwards. Hence you need to use VS 2017 with framework 4.6 or 4.7. Here is the sample running application code from [github](https://github.com/Trimble-Connect/samples). you can download this application and open in VS 2017.

You can also download other running code based on different targets from [here](https://developer.tekla.com/trimble-connect/documentation/code-examples-trimble-connect-net-sdk). Incase you are strugging with Trimble, you can write mail on 'connect-integrate@trimble.com'